# Play sound only one time, condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play sound only when my iphone have some inclination . I do this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.playing = NO;

    deviceQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 5.0 / 60.0;

    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
                                                       toQueue:deviceQueue
                                                   withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
     {
         [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
             CGFloat x = motion.gravity.x;
             CGFloat y = motion.gravity.y;
             CGFloat z = motion.gravity.z;

             CGFloat angle = atan2(y, x) + M_PI_2;           // in radians
             CGFloat angleDegrees = angle * 180.0f / M_PI;


              CGFloat r = sqrtf(x*x + y*y + z*z);
             CGFloat tiltForwardBackward = acosf(z/r) * 180.0f / M_PI - 90.0f;




             CMMotionManager* motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
             [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
             CMAccelerometerData* data = [motionManager accelerometerData];
             while ( data.acceleration.x == 0 )
             {
                 data = [motionManager accelerometerData];
             }
             NSLog(@"x = %f, y = %f, z = %f.", data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y, data.acceleration.z);

             NSLog(@"angleDegrees = %f, anglee = %f", angleDegrees, angle);
             NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"End-clap" ofType:@"mp3"];
             NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

             NSError *error = nil;
             _audioPlayer4 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
             _audioPlayer4.delegate =self;

             if (angleDegrees<180 && angleDegrees>0) {
                 self.guessImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"guessit-Recovered.png"];
                 self.wordLabel.text=@"Justin Bieber";
                             }
           else
             {
             self.wordLabel.text=@"Place on Forehead";

                 if ([self.wordLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Place on Forehead"]) {
                     if(_playing)
                     {


                         _audioPlayer4.numberOfLoops=1;
                         self.wordLabel.text=@"Justin";
                         [_audioPlayer4 play];
                         self.playing=YES;}


                 }


             }

         }];
     }];


}


    - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
    {
        NSLog(@"playing has finished");
        self.playing = NO;
    }
```

and it's playing , but only the beginig , one second and then start again and again without finish all the sound .

I suppose that is because  of angleDegrees which is changing all the time . ANy ideea how can o solve this , please ?

Comment: Hmm, your code looks OK to me - I don't see why that's happening, unless `[AVAudioPlayer playing]` is lying. Add some logging in that area.

Comment: What method is this code in ? How is it triggered ? On orientation change ?

Comment: in viewDidLoad , yes.on orientation change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a `BOOL` to indicate that the player is playing and make use of a delegate callback that denotes the stopping of the player.

```
@property(atomic) BOOL playing;
```

Once the first `if` condition is met, set is to `YES`.

According to Apple's documentation on property `playing`:

> Do not poll this property to determine when playback has completed,
>   instead implement the specified delegate method.

Instead, we rely on the following delegate method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"playing has finished");
    self.playing = NO;
}
```

In order to get callback'ed, we need to set ourself as the `delegate`:

```
_audioPlayer4 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
_audioPlayer4.delegate = self;
```

Finally, we can replace your inner `if` with:

```
if(!playing)
{
     self.playing = YES;
     NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"End-clap" ofType:@"mp3"];
     NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

     .......

    [_audioPlayer4 play];
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad`, set your property to `NO`, initially:

```
self.playing = NO;
```

Addendum:

Make sure your controller adopt to the protocol, as well.

i.e.,

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

Comment: audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is not called . I set delegate and i adopted the protocol :(

Comment: i set it at the begining of viewDidLoad . and yes , the sound is playing , but the same problem .

Comment: I update my question . Please take a look . I really apreciate your help . The ideea is when the phone is tilt to faces the sky to play a sound and when he;s tilt to faces the floor another sound

Answer (score 0):

Because angleDegrees is changing all the time. so you should set a state indicates that the sound is playing. if it is playing , you can't play it again until it finished.

Comment: I see that you already checked the playing state of audio player. maybe you can print some log to see the condition result of if(!_audioPlayer4.playing). you should find out why it is false when audio playing